# How do I calculate the real power curve of a PWM resistive load supplied by rectified AC?

Tags: pwm, bridge-rectifier, heater, calculation, resistive-load

When AC is put through a capacitor filtered full wave rectifier, the output voltage is ~1.414 x RMS input voltage for zero load, and nominally equivalent to the RMS voltage when connected to a pure resistive load (assuming the capacitor is large enough that voltage ripple becomes negligible.

But what if you used a PWM circuit to control how much power flows to the load? ***How would you determine the relationship of PWM duty cycle to net average power output?***

It's obviously not linear, as a quick check shows: An ideal resistive heating element draws 10kW at 250VAC. 250V rectified is about 353V with no current flowing. Considering the near-zero edge case, with simplifying assumptions, 1% PWM duty cycle doesn't produce 1% of the max power (100W), but about 2%, or 196W (~350V^2 / 6.25 ohms * 1%).

How would I calculate the expected net average power for any arbitrary PWM duty cycle for such a system?

This question has been edited to remove details un-related to the core question.  For the curious, see edit history and some of the comments.

Comment: Just out of curiousity, have you calculated the capacitance and voltage ratings for the two capacitors you mention? It seems to me that the cost and size of these should be inversely proportional to the variation in power delivered to the load over time (either over ac cycle or pwm cycle). So if you want perfectly "smooth" power, with zero variation, then the cost of the capacitors will be....

Comment: I have not done the capacitor calculation yet, but I'm more interested at this point in understanding the theoretical behavior of the system, with idealized steady-state conditions, which is why I didn't add more detail about the design.  The only question I'm really concerned with is, "What should I expect the relationship of duty cycle to heating power to be?" within 5% or so.  Enough that if my control calls for 1500W, or 3850W or 6200W, it knows where to set the PWM.

Comment: *this SHOULD deliver infinitely adjustable power to the heater, while maintaining a smooth current draw from the mains.* - absolutely NOT. Next: *Rectified AC will produce a DC voltage equal to the Peak to Peak voltage of the incoming AC* - wrong - it will be the peak voltage. So get rid of all the wrongness in your question and stop guessing things and focus down on what you really want to know. I reckon you can deliver a reasonable question in less than 30 words.

Comment: What type of heater is it, and what is it 'treating'?

Comment: Kanthal A1 coiled heating element.  The unit will be used for hardening / tempering / annealing various tool steels, stainless steel, inconel, as well as occasionally melting non-ferrous alloys, cast iron and glass.

Comment: @Mike It's not fair to people to have answered to delete answers. And while editing questions rather than posting new ones is generally preferred, if the edit shifts the question too far the answers may be irrelevant. MAybe a note at the start of the question proper along the lines of "I have edited this question in line with recommendations ... maybe very brief summary of change ...  brief statement of key aim ... .

Comment: Comment to several people:  Ignoring snarky / rude comments by others is recommended . Firefights help nobody. Do note that it's wise to leave out personal criticism in comments and answers.  | Happy new year Y'All.

Answer (score 1):

Some comments:

1. It's not clear why you would choose open-loop control instead of using closed loop control with temperature feedback.
2. Is the thermal response time of your setup really so fast that you couldn't, for example, alternate between 32 and 33 AC cycles per second to get any value in between? You don't need timebases in the order of seconds. You could use a timebase of 1 s (2% step size or 1% if you allow half-cycles) or variable timebase.
3. Rectifying mains will give horrible current pulses on the mains, poor power factor and high harmonics. This is in breach of your EMI requirements.
4. Adding a capacitor after a PWM in parallel with the load is going to be big, expensive and place extra demands on your PWM switcher as well as messing up your calculations.

> Rectified AC will produce a DC voltage equal to the Peak to Peak voltage of the incoming AC when no current is being drawn (PWM 0%).

Unless you're using a centre-tapped transformer you'll just get the peak voltage.

> When rectified AC is fed directly into a resistive load, the average voltage will drop to the RMS voltage of the supply (less diode losses, etc).

No, we use the RMS value because it gives the true heating effect. Average value does not.

> In order to accurately set up the control loop to operate at a wide variety of temperatures, I need to be able to predict the real power output at any arbitrary PWM duty cycle.

No, the whole idea of feedback control loops is that we no longer need a linear system. Think of the cruise control on your car; speed as a function of throttle position is non-linear. It's the same with heating systems as heat loss increases with temperature.

> Because the power source is unregulated rectified AC, the average voltage (and thus average power) will vary depending on the average current draw, which is dependent on the duty cycle.

Doing whole-cycle duty-cycle makes this a very simple calculation.

> If the output is 7kW (240V^2 / ~8.23 ohms) at 100%, then in an ideal situation, 1% duty cycle would give 70W.

Yes, 7 kW at 1% duty cycle gives 70 W on a 240 V full-wave rectified DC.

> But this cannot be the case, because with ZERO current, the DC would be about 340 V. So a 1% duty cycle at 340 V would be really be somewhere in the ballpark of 140W (340<sup>2</sup> / 8.23 ohm). Looking at this single edge case, it's apparent this isn't a linear system, at least in terms of power.

Correct, because your capacitors have messed up the simple system. And we haven't even started to consider capacitor droop yet.

**I think you need to clarify in your own head why you think you need infinite control and why you need a linear response to the control input. Everyone else is using variable duty-cycle on non-linear systems with a suitable control system.**

One more thing: another non-linearity not accounted for in your scheme is the positive temperature coefficient of the heating wire.

Comment: With that comment I'm content merely to make myself look smart by pointing out all the flaws in your question. Bye.

Comment: OP or moderator has deleted offensive comment, "*Are you content merely to make yourself look smart by pointing out all the flaws in my question.*" Others beware.

Comment: Just to be clear, I don't need a linear system, I need a predictable system.  I can compensate for the non-linearity in the element itself and the heat loss as a function of temperature and other factors.  I will be using a closed-loop control similar to a PID, but it's more sophisticated because simple PID controllers don't have consistent performance across very large swings in operating conditions BECAUSE of the many non-linear factors.  A control loop tuned at 2400 degrees would be unstable or less responsive at 600 degrees, and vice versa.

Comment: @transistor Wasn't me, and I think you mean "before"

Comment: @VoltageSpike, thanks. No, I meant "beware".

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid load spikes or EMI on the mains input you need something a bit more sophisticated than a full wave rectifier and capacitor.

At minimum you would need an inductive input such as:

[Choke input filter](https://www.tpub.com/neets/book7/27f.htm)

The modern way however would be to use a power factor corrected (PFC) power supply, they are actually required in most jurisdictions above a certain power level. From the point of view of the incoming mains the load acts like a resistor with the current being in phase with the voltage and no spikes at the peak as with a normal rectifier.

[How the Boost PFC Converter Circuit Improves Power Quality](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/technical-articles/how-the-boost-pfc-converter-circuit-improves-power-quality/)

This would also have the advantage that the voltage to the heater could be regulated so the issue with the voltage declining as the power output changes would be avoided.

Comment: Good point.  I forgot about the current pulses due to voltage ripple on the main smoothing capacitor. Thanks for pointing that out.

I appreciate the info about the Boost PFC converter.  It looks like an excellent solution, but seems like it would be prohibitively expensive for an off-the-shelf unit in the 7kW range.

Comment: @MikeMikkelsen - Agreed, it can avoid the cost of a large input transformer though. Most electric vehicle chargers use this technology at about the same power level - 6.6-7.2kW with 240V input.

Answer (score 0):

First, what @KevinWhite said about PFC inputs -- just running AC into a rectifier with a capacitor filter makes for really spiky current.  Running AC into a rectifier with a choke filter makes for a square-wave current -- which has a better power factor than a capacitor-input filter, but it's still not *good*.

Second, you're just going to need to temperature-control your oven (or whatever).  The uncertainty in the heater drive that you would get using a simple capacitor-input filter can then just be folded into the overall error budget of your oven; a good controller will make it all work even if the PWM command to heat output curve is a bit nonlinear.